# Copy Stage on IBM Data Stage

Tags: transformer-model, datastage

I found a strange thing while using Copy Data to insert data into a table.
All columns are processed in a transformer and there are two special columns in the transformer.

Column A uses index function to perform LIKE operation in a string.
Column B is the string to be used column A and it is sorted by alphabetical order in one column.

The following code is using index function to assign a value of Column A.

```
IF index(COL_B, "ABC", 1) >0 THEN 'ABC' ELSE COL_B
```

My expected result on the target table is Column A to have 'ABC' or the original string of Column B.
When I checked out the table, column A was not changed at all.

***BTW, after placing one transformer between COPY stage and Target table, the column A is updated.***

I couldn't find the reason why it happened or any clue/explanation by googling. Is it normal result when we use a COPY stage? If so, our team should know it can happen all the time.

1. Original flow - not update column A and B

[image]

2. Added a transformer between COPY and Target table - updated column A and B

[image]

======================================================

**[Updates]**

1. This error is not reproduced regardless of the creation a new job by copying the original job and a target table on the Oracle.
2. The original job and the copied job are sending the correct dataflow without Stage Variables once the dataflow was corrected by one more transformer even though the 2nd transformer was removed after the correction.
3. Due to #1 updates, Stage Variables in the transformer in the original job works well, but I couldn't have the exact testing against the incorrect dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

<s>A common reason for such code not to work is the order in which columns are processed.</s>

The compiler might mix it up when trying to optimize the job. This is actually valid, because even though we *see* a top-down sorting of the columns, the columns *can* be treated as non-sorted. (The Connector Stage should map the columns by name.) <sup>*I might have mixed something up here, but the following suggestion is still valid:*</sup>

In Trans_1, substitute your code in Stage Variables. These are processed top-down.

If the problem still exists:

- Try to play around with the force option of the copy stage
- or contact IBM support for in-depth analysis.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and suggestion. Would you please share any document mentioning about the processing order in COPY stage? If so, I would appreciate it. After posting my question, one more question came into my mind. In the original job flow, only one TRANS sends all data after applying index function. I believed COPY stage receives the dataset from 'transformer' applied sorted COLUMN A and applied index function for COLUMN B. In the original result, it looks like not applied the index function and sorting to COLUMN A, B in transformer or COPY stage makes changes on them.

Comment: I only can contacted IBM via its website and customer service line once. Could you let me know if there is a better way to contact IBM to receive some information in terms of technical analysis? I'm not sure if my team will try on it. But I believe it doesn't hurts anything if I have the contact information now.

Comment: The processing order I mentioned refers to the Transformer Stage. 

If your company bought DataStage, they usually also bought support. Ask your team who has access to the IBM support.

Comment: Thanks again. I found an example using Stage variables in the Transformer Stage since I never tried it out before. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEOQjjwaXU0 Now I probably understand the concept of TOP-DOWN because Stage Variables are on the top in the Transformer. Hope it is correct understanding about your explanation.

Comment: FYI, in the picture 2, I added TRANS 2 and applied index function again between COPY stage and Target table, all the columns were updated. Moreover, although I removed TRANS 2 and re-ran the job, the target table started to be populated along with the expected values. The target table is always truncated, so it looks like DataStage learned something from the new pattern. I'm still not sure the reason, but it is a new observation for me.

Comment: I think my answer is wrong and I should delete it. The suggestion of using STage variables is still valid, but after thinking about the column order, I might be wrong because you cannot derive an output column from another output column but only from an input column or stage Variables. You should remove the acception of this answer.

Comment: Regardless of the acceptance, you gave me really useful information about this problem. In the original dataflow, the problem maybe caused by the order in the Transformer or optimization by Copy stage. BTW, I just only had thought about COPY before this posting. Now I separate the steps - Transformer testing and COPY testing. Thanks again.

Comment: I want to share what I had testing about the dataflow. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the error regardless of the creation of the exact same job and table by copying the original job and a target table on Oracle. Due to this situation, I couldn't confirm whether Stage Variables in the transformer corrects the wrong dataflow in the end. BTW, I could learn a new knowledge and tips about building a job in DS.